# Dyna-Q in non-deterministic domains

Tags: artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning

I've implemented the [Dyna-Q](https://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~sutton/book/ebook/node96.html) reinforcement learning algorithm and it works perfectly on a discrete deterministic environment, the [cliff](https://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~sutton/book/ebook/node65.html). However, when applying it to a continuous environment ([mountain car](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mountain_Car)) with discretized states (which [introduces non-determinism](https://www.academia.edu/14203296/On_determinism_handling_while_learning_reduced_state_space_representations)), it fails everytime (using function approximation is not in question here).

My question is: Sutton's description of Dyna-Q explicitly mentions its applicability to deterministic domains. Are there necessary tweaks for it to work in non-deterministic domains?

Answer (score 2):

One approach is outlined in Tucker Balch's Machine Learning for Trading course on Udacity:

- [Learning T](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bSY5waB4Myo)
- [Learning R](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n_jiudhCSv8)

In a nutshell: create a $T_c$ table ("T count") that counts the number of times each subsequent state is reached after taking an action in a given state. Initialize all values to 0.00001 to avoid division by 0 errors. While executing QLearning, observe $s,a,s^\prime$ and increment $T_c[s,a,s^\prime]$.

Formula for calculating the probability of each s' from [s,a]

$$ \frac{T_c[s,a,s^\prime]}{\sum_i T_c[s,a,i]}$$

- The numerator is the count of times s,a lead to each s'.
- The denominator is the sum of $T_c[s,a,:]$ (normalizes each s' to its probability)

Dyna-Q then updates a state's expected reward as the weighted sum of the reward in each s' weighted by their relative probability.